# -v vs -version vs --version

Tags: bash, unix, package, version

I'm using OS X. I've always used `<package name> -v` and known of it as a shortcut for `<package name> --version`. But I've recently seen a few instances of people using `<package name> -version` (one hyphen). Is there any difference between these commands?

Comment: That's about convention. `java` uses for instance `-version`. Think this might be better suitable for SO Super User.

Answer (score 1):

Different commands have different command syntaxes, typically for historical reasons<sup>1</sup>.

There is no fundamental difference in the meaning of `-version` and `--version`.  You just have to use the version option that the particular command supports.  (It is usually easy find out which one / ones work.)

This is a bit like the different spellings of words; e.g.

- colour versus color
- gray versus grey

except that the application typically *doesn't* understand the "other" kind of version option.

---

The POSIX.1-2017 standard documents the command syntax conventions here:

- [12.2 Utility Syntax Guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)

but notice that it only calls them "guidelines".  Adherence to the guidelines is not mandatory.

---

<sup>1 - For example, the Java commands have used one `-` for their long-form options since the first public release of Java in ~1997.  They decided not to change it because they didn't want to break users' scripts<sup>2</sup>.  For another example of unconventional options, look at the command syntax of the `tar` command.</sup>

<sup>2 - There is an issue about "-version" in Java Bug Database.  It was marked as "Wont Fix" a long time ago.</sup>

Comment: Understood, thanks. So all three do the same thing. What could those historical reasons be though? Like, say `--version` already existed, why would someone want to make it so that `-version` worked as well? Wouldn't they assume it would be confusing?

Comment: Well, to comment on this: Is there really a standard how to print version information? There are so called long. vs short options. Different flavors/flavours (SCNR) just exist, as @StephenC explained already.

Comment: @stephanmg - It is a convention, not a standard.  The convention is supported by libraries such as the GNU getopts library, but some software predates the emergence (or wide adoption) of the convention.

Comment: The reason is that there is no standard for - and -- in general. For example `find` uses single dashes to introduce word options.

Comment: The POSIX standard includes the convention of single-hyphen options, with clusters of options preceded by `-` being shorthand for each option listed separately (e.g., `-fbx` is short for `-f -b -x`), and `--` as the argument that signals the end of option processing.